# Setting up VM's with a SAN

Tags: virtual-machines, storage-area-network

I am currently in the Process of virtualizing my infrastructure setting up a SAN As well as a complete replica as a DR site. I have purchased the following Equipment (plus all other needed equipment)

DL360 Gen9 x4 (2 for production and 2 for DR site)

HPE MSA 2050 x2 (1 for production and 1 for DR site)

I have VSphere 6.7 ESXi installed on the DL360's.

My first question is should I install the VM's on the Local drives or should I put them on the SAN?

Secondly, in the past I have put VCenter on its own server. With the addition of the SAN should I keep VCenter on a separate server, a VM on the Host or a VM on the SAN? I have never setup a SAN before so this portion is new to me.

Lastly, how will replication and fail-over between the Production and DR site be affected by where install the VM's

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is should I install the VM's on the Local drives or should I put them on the SAN?

Running your VMs on virtualized storage is the point of setting up a storage network.

> With the addition of the SAN should I keep VCenter on a separate server, a VM on the Host or a VM on the SAN?

There are pros and cons for a virtual vCenter server. With a good setup and recovery scheme, a virtual vCenter is better to handle but there's more that can go wrong. With a VM, you don't want to run it on DAS.

> Lastly, how will replication and fail-over between the Production and DR site be affected by where install the VM's

When a host goes down its local storage will not be accessible, all VMs on it permanently offline. With VMs on virtualized storage you can migrate them and run them elsewhere (even automatically).